# Meaning of "integral function" in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functions

As used, for instance, in Parthasarathy's "A Theorem on Integral Functions." (https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-28/3/377/865912?redirectedFrom=PDF)

From google it seems that it is an old-fashioned term in complex analysis but I cannot find where it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Integral function* and *entire function* are synonymous. Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) Wikipedia entry.

Comment: Thank you! My undoing was in googling "'integral function' complex" and not "'integral function' complex analysis"!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays they call an integral function "entire", i.e. it is holomorphic on the entire complex plane.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function