# Definition of Integral Function-Davenport

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory has a chapter on Integral Function of Order $1$. Chapter $11$.

He uses the word 'Integral Function' but I am not sure what it means. I could not find its definition in the book either.

Are integral function are entire function? or it means something else.

Comment: Yes, it mean an entire function. Just look at the first sentence of the Wikipedia page for entire functions: "In complex analysis, an entire function, also called an integral function, is a complex-valued function that is holomorphic on the whole complex plane."  And see a previous MSE page: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082467/meaning-of-integral-function-in-complex-analysis.

Comment: alright, thank you for clarification